# ある端末へのパケットを遮断したい

Tags: network

LAN(VLAN)内で、ある端末へパケットが届かないようにしたいです。
あるいは、ある端末からのパケットをどこにも届かないようにする、でも構いません。
一時的、あるいは簡単に復旧できる形が望ましいのですが、
例えばブロードキャストで偽装arpパケットを送信しダミーの端末に送らせる、等はできるのでしょうか。

補足
XY問題である、と指摘いただいたので訂正します。
VLAN内に、物理的にどこにあるかわからない、NASやルータがつなぎ間違えられたとします。
それが原因で他の端末がネットに繋がらなくなってしまった時に、
原因を見つけるまでのの応急処置として原因特定作業中も他の端末がネットを使えるようにしたいです。

原因である端末のipアドレス・MACアドレスを使って、原因である端末へのパケットを遮断すれば良いのではないかと考えました。
そして、例えば偽装ARPによって他の全端末のARPテーブルを書き換えれば実現できるのかも、と考えました。
arpによる手法や、あるいはの手法で解決できないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: IPアドレス/MACアドレスが分かった時点で該当端末をそのままフィルタリングにかける、ではダメなのでしょうか。該当の端末を制御できるかは別として、ネットワークの話であれば物理的な位置はあまり意味が無い気がします。

Comment: フィルタリングにかけるについて詳しく教えてください。

Comment: 家庭用の製品を含め、大抵のルーターには「IPフィルタリング」の設定が備わっており、IPアドレス/MACアドレスやポート番号を指定してパケットを遮断・または許可することができます。 [参考：YAMAHAのルーター](http://www.yamaha.com/products/zh/network/ja/solution/sec_mac/)

Comment: オイラんとこでネットワーク障害が発生したときは物理的原因のことが多くて（ループさせちゃったとか、ケーブルが断線してたとか）結局のところ位置特定の上、物理除去する羽目になりました。ＩＰフィルタリングでなんとかできるとしたら物理障害が無い場合に限るので、それでうまくいけば御の字ですね。

Comment: そもそも、勝手にクライアントとしてぶら下がるだけならまだしも、周りに障害を引き起こしかねないものが簡単にネットワークに繋げられる運用の方が根本的な問題な気がします。

Comment: `それが原因で他の端末がネットに繋がらなくなってしまった時に、`が何を想定しているのかが気になる。DHCPで振られたIPと静的アドレスが衝突とか？それでもすぐにつながらんようにはならんと思うんですが…loop構造作っちゃったとかなら分からんでも無いですが...

Comment: 返信遅れて申し訳ありません。沢山のコメントありがとうございます。まず、ルータのフィルタリング機能では、特定の端末がルータ外へのパケットを遮断することは出来ても、LAN内での通信まで遮断することは出来ないと思っています。スイッチングハブを多数使用しているというのもあります。

Comment: 物理的なループや断線の場合は、原因の特定方法がMACアドレスやipアドレスでないので、今回の対策では考えていません。何とかして位置特定します。

Comment: 運用方法が怪しい、とありますが、注意喚起はしておりますので強化するなり何らかの管理体制を考えるなりします。取り敢えず今回はパケットを遮断出来ないか、という質問ですのでお願い致します。

Comment: 他の端末がネットに繋がらなくなるのは何を想定しているのか、ですが、NASの設定ミス・接続ミスなどによる不正なDHCPサーバや、勘違いからルータをハブ替わりにされてしまった時などです。

Answer (score 1):

LAN ケーブルを物理的に抜いちゃうとか（おおマジ）一時的かつ簡単に復旧できます。

なんだかＸＹ問題な感じがしますが、真にやりたいことはなんでしょう？

Comment: 物理的にどこにあるかわからない、つなぎ間違えたNASなどのせいでほかの端末がネットに繋がらなくなってしまった時に、原因を見つけるまでのの応急処置として作業中もほかの端末がネットを使えるようにしたいのです。